# How to compute explicit equations for the Jacobian of a variety over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, computational-geometry, jacobians

Suppose we start with a projective curve $X$ over a field $K$, given as a closed subvariety of $\mathbb P^n_K$ by some explicit list of equations. I would like to find an explicit representation of the Jacobian variety of $X$, as closed subvariety of $\mathbb P^r_K$ (I don't particularly care about the value of $r$, but smaller is better) by a list of equations, together with a similarly explicit list of equations for the morphisms $\operatorname{Jac} X \times \operatorname{Jac} X \to \operatorname{Jac} X$ and $\operatorname{Jac} X \to \operatorname{Jac} X$ expressing the addition and inversion on the Jacobian.

Is there any algorithmic way to do this?

Comment: @IgorRivin Your earlier question was about Jacobians of curves, this question seems to be asking about "Jacobians" of general projective varieties. Of course, usually people don't talk about Jacobians in that setting, but probably the OP means the abelian variety representing $\text{Pic}^0(X)$, or alternatively maybe the Albanese variety of $X$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Ah, indeed. As you say, I had assumed that the OP REALLY meant curves, but perhaps he can enlighten us :)

Comment: @JoeSilverman you are right, $X$ was supposed to be a curve, not just any variety. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @IgorRivin thanks for your link, I will have a closer look at it later today, but it looks promising.